# Magento 2: Paypal Express Checkout: We can't place the order

Tags: magento2, orders, error, paypal, paypal-express

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2. Facing strange issue. My website is live.

Using Paypal Express Checkout. We are using CDN & SSL.

Out of 100 Customers 10 Customers will face above kind of issue. When i turn on `Debug Mode ON`

I have below ones in the log.

> 'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Shipping Address1 Empty', 'L_LONGMESSAGE0' =>
>   'The field Shipping Address1 is required',
>
> 'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Shipping Address Postal Code Empty',
>   'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The field Shipping Address Postal Code is
>   required',
>
> 'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Customer must choose new funding sources.',
>   'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The customer must return to PayPal to select new
>   funding sources.',

**When i check Customer Address on Admin they have all the information.** We disabled Guest Checkout.

The issue is where is data loss from Paypal to Magento? How can solve this issue 100%, so no user will face this issue.

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Sending address to Paypal is not working well.

Also, in this similar issue, it seems that Paypal doesn't recommends to send address : [Paypal Express Checkout without shipping address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149827/paypal-express-checkout-without-shipping-address/220953#220953)

To disable it in Express Checkout, you have to create a plugin :

Declare module - **/app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php** :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Declare Plugin - **/app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="namespaceModuleNvp" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Model\Api\NvpPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin file - **/app/code/Namespace/Module/Plugin/Model/Api/NvpPlugin.php** :

```
<?php

namespace Webart\Base\Plugin\Model\Api;

/**
 * Class NvpPlugin
 * @package Webart\Base\Plugin\Model\Api
 */
class NvpPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param $methodName
     * @param array $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function aroundCall(\Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp $subject, callable $proceed, $methodName, array $request)
    {
        $request['NOSHIPPING'] = 1; // All this stuff for that ;-)
        return $proceed($methodName, $request);
    }
}
```