# Paypal express checkout magento 2 - Shipping address is invalid when place order using Russian country and address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, paypal-express

I am using magento 2.1.13 and facing issue with paypal express checkout.

When I place and order using China, Japan, and Us. it's working but when I place an order using Russian country with their address it's showing me error "we can't place an order" I check debug log and it's showing "Shipping address is invalid." I try to many more address from Russia but same issue is there. here is paypal log.

```
 array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'DoExpressCheckoutPayment' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-33D21907WX527562D',
    'PAYERID' => 'UTZY4EHG8787G',
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Authorization',
    'AMT' => '13.00',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
    'NOTIFYURL' => 'https://mysite/paypal/ipn/',
    'RETURNFMFDETAILS' => 1,
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '5.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '8.00',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'Calming oz',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '8.00',
    'BUSINESS' => NULL,
    'EMAIL' => 'pratik.kk@yahoo.com',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Pratik',
    'LASTNAME' => 'asasas',
    'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
    'SALUTATION' => NULL,
    'SUFFIX' => NULL,
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'RU',
    'STATE' => '',
    'CITY' => 'Nizhnelunohodsk ',
    'STREET' => 'Svetlaya ul. Apt 191',
    'ZIP' => '877561 ',
    'PHONENUM' => '35535353',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'RU',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'AD',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'Nizhnelunohodsk ',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'Svetlaya ul. Apt 191',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '877561 ',
    'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '35535353',
    'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
    'STREET2' => '',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'Pratik asasas',
    'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
    'METHOD' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-33D21907WX527562D',
    'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED' => 'false',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2018-07-03T11:30:03Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => 'd23e3f82f3c47',
    'ACK' => 'Failure',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '000000',
    'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10424',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'Shipping address is invalid.',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  ),
```

Comment: Most probably this is not it, but it's worth checking. According to [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/country-codes/#) for Russia, the zip code is required. And you have a blank space at the end of your zip code. Make sure you enter a valid Russian zip code. You can get one from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Russia

Comment: Marius,

Thank your for your reply. But it seems problem with not zip code space.
Paypal Express checkout is not working when we select Russian as country.

I have tried with magento 1 version and magento 2 version also and all version have same problem

Comment: Maybe you should contact paypal about this. I didn't find anything in their documentation that might suggest it is disabled for russia.

Comment: @Marius i am not sure but same issue have on magento 2 git hub issue list link is here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16556

Comment: I think issue in "SHIPTOCITY and ZIP".

Comment: Temporary solution is to disable shipping address for paypal express like its here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149974/magento-2-paypal-express-checkout-we-cant-place-the-order

Comment: @BartZalas It's not working.

Comment: Why is space after ZIP number at the end   'ZIP' => '877561 ',    Autofill?

Comment: Anyway this postcode is wrong 877561 in Russia first three numbers is post code of town next three is house number. I checked in wikipedia there is no town with 877 postcode number

Comment: Wrong town also https://postalcode.globefeed.com/Russia_Postal_Code.asp

Comment: Ok Let me check.